# Multiplying a new column by a number if the np.where is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multiplication

I am trying to multiply this column by a number if the condition is met. If it is I want the august_report['Monthly Recurring Charge'] column to be multiplied by a number such as 20.

```
august_report['Activation Commission'] = np.where((august_report['Line activity'] == 'Activation')&(august_report['Activation type'] == 'Lease'),np.multiply(august_report['Monthly Recurring Charge'],20))
```

Comment: What would your desired output look like? How does your data look like? please post a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC this is what you're looking for:

```
august_report['Activation Commission'] = np.where((august_report['Line activity'] == 'Activation')&(august_report['Activation type'] == 'Lease'),august_report['Monthly Recurring Charge']*20, 'condition not met'))
```

If you want to preserve the original value when the condition isn't met you replace `'condition not met'` by `august_report['Monthly Recurring Charge']`

Comment: that is it, I just made a syntax error, sorry for my novice mistake.

Comment: You shouldn't be sorry, just try to get better !

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is what you are looking for

```
august_report['Activation Commission'] = np.where((august_report['Line activity'] == 'Activation')&(august_report['Activation type'] == 'Lease'),august_report['Activation Commission']*august_report['Monthly Recurring Charge'],"a number")
```

Comment: sorry if this was unclear, i edited my explanation.